# How to create Account Share Record

Tags: apex

Hi i have requirement to create sharing records for account. But When i try to create AccountSHare record it gives me a error DML Operation not allowed.

Here is the code

```
String query =' Select Id FROM Account WHERE '+String.join(whereClause,'AND');
     List<Account> accounts = Database.query(query) ;
     List<AccountShare> share = new List<AccountShare>();

     for(Account a:accounts){
        AccountShare accountShare = new AccountShare();
        accountShare.AccountId = a.Id;
        accountShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId;
        accountShare.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
        accountShare.ContactAccessLevel = 'Edit';
        accountShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
        share.add( accountShare);
     }

     insert share;
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, sneha. Can you elaborate on your question? When and where are you trying to use AccountShare (trigger, batch Apex, other)? If you can share your code you'll get a better response.

Comment: I am trying to use account share in apex class which is called from the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for adding in code, sneha. I assume the SELECT works and you get the error on the Insert?

Comment: Please post the entire text of the error.

Comment: What is the Organization-Wide Default sharing level on the Account object? If it's Public Read/Write, the AccountShare table is not available.

Comment: Mike , yes i get an error while inserting the records. @DanielHoechst the entire error message is DML operation INSERT not allowed on AccountShare

Answer (score 4):

My first suggestion would be to modify `String.join(whereClause,'AND')` to `String.join(whereClause,' AND ')` [adding spaces before and after AND] otherwise your where clause would yield 'WHERE Id = IdANDName = NameANDField__c = Field

My second suggestion would be to add `accountShare.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';` to your record since AccountShare has all four

```
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ' + String.join(whereClause,' AND ');
List<Account> accounts = Database.query(query);
List<AccountShare> share = new List<AccountShare>();

for(Account acc : accounts){
     AccountShare accountShare = new AccountShare();
          accountShare.AccountId = acc.Id;
          accountShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId;
          accountShare.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
          accountShare.ContactAccessLevel = 'Edit';
          accountShare.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
          accountShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
     share.add(accountShare);
}

insert share;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Contact sharing model is set to `Controlled by Parent` then you cannot set the `ContactAccessLevel` in `AccountShare`.

Comment: No. The error i am getting is DML Operation not allowed

Comment: Are you testing with multiple Accounts at once? Maybe try inserting by doing Database.Insert(share,false) and run through the results. It might be only a subset of your inserts failing so maybe that helps in finding the cause.

Comment: Also I had problems inserting AccountShare records if there was already a manual sharing rule for that Account for that particular groupId. So you might want to query for that before doing the insert.